# cant change font type in dynamic image

Tags: php, gd

cant seem to get the font to work , so far i've seen that the imagestring doesn't support the font being changed so im trying to work with imagettftext like so

```
imagettftext($finalImage, 20, 0, 11, 21, $textcolorBlue, $font2, $text);
```

but instead of displaying any text , it just shows the image with all the imagestring's written , also this is my first time working with dynamic images so , im not quite sure what im doing wrong (if any thing) also Neverwinter.ttf is in the same file directory as the image script  any help would be appriciated

```
<?php



    $image = imagecreatefrompng("icons.png");
    imagesavealpha($image, true);
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    $size = getimagesize("icons.png");

    $finalImage = imagecreatetruecolor(320,125);


     $font = imageloadfont('/runescape/phpfile/arial.ttf');
    $font2 = imageloadfont('Neverwinter.ttf');
     $font = 4;
    $textcolorBlack = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 0, 0, 0);
     $textcolorWhite = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 255, 255, 255);
    $textcolorGreen = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 0, 255, 0);
    $textcolorBlue = imagecolorallocate($finalImage, 225,225, 255);

      imagecopy($finalImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 320, 125);

    //imagestring($finalImage, $font, 0, 0, 'random', $textcolorBlue);


    $text = 'testing...';
     imagettftext($finalImage, 20, 0, 11, 21, $textcolorBlue, $font2, $text);






    // Content type
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($finalImage);



    ?>
```

Comment: please only post relevant code.

Comment: @Dagon , fixed with relevent code - the reason i posted it all is , i wasn't sure if part of my code was causing a problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the line

```
$font2 = imageloadfont('Neverwinter.ttf');
```

to

```
$font2 = 'path/Neverwinter.ttf';
```

Comment: thanks, working now, do you happen to know why it doesnt like imageloadfont('Neverwinter.ttf); ?

Comment: no, i dont know, actually i never hear of that function :p